# Inner product with homomorphic encryption

Tags: reference-request, homomorphic-encryption

I want to do a very simple thing: Given two vectors, I want to encrypt them and do some calculation, then decrypt the result and get the inner product between both vectors. I want to do this as fast as possible for the biggest vector dimension possible.

Can you recommend any reference which may help me understand things and how to do it?

Or maybe you can even point me to some library that can do this? I found HELIB, but I don´t know if that is the best solution for my purpose. Since I have only basic knowledge in cryptography, I´ld like use it as black box as much as possible without having to put too much effort in the math behind it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but this may be a programming-related question with crypto-background. This *may* better live at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com). I think this will be close-voted as off-topic as you aren't interested in the FHE itself.

Comment: If you ask about which libraries to use, this is off topic. If you ask which cryptosystem has a particular property, it would be on topic. Please [edit] your question to make sure it is on topic so that it will not be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use these schemes instead:

- [“Evaluating 2-DNF Formulas on Ciphertexts”](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/papers/2dnf.pdf), or
- [“A Simple BGN-type Cryptosystem from LWE”](http://people.csail.mit.edu/vinodv/lwe-bgn.pdf).

These schemes enable you to do addition, a single multiplication, and more additions. For inner product, that's all you need (encrypt each item separately, multiply pairs, and add all together).

Not everything needs FHE. In any case, somewhat HE would suffice since it's just a single multiplication.

Comment: can i find any implementation to this scheme?

Comment: Not that I know. The second one may be easier to implement; I'm not sure - you need to check.

Comment: what about matrix multiplication?

Comment: Matrix multiplication is just a lot of single multiplications followed by addition. There is no multiplication following a multiplication, so all should be fine. Check the paper.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must know what homomorphic encryption system can support inner product as you want. I hope that [Dario Catalano, Dario Fiore - Boosting Linearly-Homomorphic Encryption to Evaluate Degree-2 Functions on Encrypted Data](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/813) can help you.

Comment: Please, always provide context for links. Our help-center explains why: *[“Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.”](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)*